# Auto Create Columns Using Single Plain List

Tags: html, css, dynamic, html-lists, css-multicolumn-layout

I am trying to write flexible code where I have one plain `<ul>` which gets automatically creates another column for every 5th element. I have found a [tutorial](http://csswizardry.com/2010/02/mutiple-column-lists-using-one-ul/) that achieves this but places the items in a horizontal order whereas I require a vertical order. I have seen some other tutorials that outputs a vertical order, but also attaches `class="first"` and `class="second"` to each `li` which is not what I want. I am looking to do with with my existing HTML code.

What I Want:

```
-01     -06     -11   
-02     -07     -12
-03     -08     -13
-04     -09     -14
-05     -10     -15
```

What I Have:

```
-01     -02     -03   
-04     -05     -06
-07     -08     -09
-10     -11     -12
-13     -14     -15
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    width:760px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

li {   
    float:left;
    display:inline;
}

.double li  { width:50.0%; } /* 2 col */
.triple li  { width:33.3%; } /* 3 col */
.quad li    { width:25.0%; } /* 4 col */
.six li     { width:16.6%; } /* 6 col */
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="triple">
  <li>01</li>
  <li>02</li>
  <li>03</li>
  <li>04</li>
  <li>05</li>
  <li>06</li>
  <li>07</li>
  <li>08</li>
  <li>09</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
  <li>13</li>
  <li>14</li>
  <li>15</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If you need to support IE, you're gonna have to use JavaScript or change your markup. Otherwise, you could use `:nth-child(5n)` and the like.

Comment: JavaScript is definitely an option. I can modify my HTML as long as I am not adding any classes/divs within the `ul` itself. I'll take a look at `:nth-child()`.

Comment: I think JavaScript would be a better tag than "dynamic" here...

Comment: How would you do this with JavaScript? Sorry, my JS is not that advanced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this [code](http://trentwalton.com/2010/07/19/css3-multi-column-layout-column-count/):

```
ul
{
    -webkit-column-count: 4; -webkit-column-gap:20px;
    -moz-column-count:4; -moz-column-gap:20px;
    -o-column-count:4; -o-column-gap:20px;
    column-count:4; column-gap:20px;
}
```

but I'm not sure if it works in all browsers unfortunately. You should experiment that.

Here's the jsFiddle to play with it: http://jsfiddle.net/leniel/nRL4R/

Comment: I like the solution, but unfortunately silly IE doesn't support it.

Comment: Yeah... it's a very clean solution. You just have to apply the `ul` styles and take out all the other ones. IE is really a bad guy when it comes to applying CSS properties. :)

Comment: Hm... I'll keep investigating for another solution that is compatible with IE, but I'll use this as my fall back.

Answer (score 0):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iDzmq

This is the only way i know of doing this.
just in the code you are using to render the lists set it to add a ul.sub every 5th li

Any Questions?

Comment: I don't want to be adding a `<ul class="sub">` for every 5th element. I am going to be working with lots of elements and injecting a few additional elements every now and then in random spots. Hard coding which column each element goes in my list will make my code extremely hard to maintain in the future.

Comment: What code are you using because this could always be a simple case of a loop that will take all the values in an array and then process them with a count that will add the custom class on the 5th element. if you are using PHP I can script you something up pretty quick